# Problem with installation on Asus ROG

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

I have ASUS Rog GL 552 VW Dh71 laptop . [Link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01578ZKPO)

I am not able to install Ubuntu or any Linux on my machine. I tried installation with Ubuntu 14.04, 15.10 and 16.04 beta 2 with no success.

My screen goes black after pressing install Ubuntu on grub in 16.04 and I receive error messages

```
nouveau E[ PIBUS] [000:01:00.0] HUB:0x6013d4 0x00005700 (0x1c 408200)
nouveau E[ DRM]failed to idle channel 0xccc0001 [DRM]
```

in 14.04 and 15.10, what should I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boot from Ubuntu installation media and select **Try Ubuntu without installing**.
Press the <kbd>E</kbd> key and add `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the `linux` line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the desktop, start installation of Ubuntu.

When finished, boot the installed system, select the Ubuntu GRUB menu entry.
Press the <kbd>E</kbd> key and add `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the `linux` line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into Ubuntu system, install the NVIDIA drivers.

Reboot the system - from now on you don't have to add a parameter any more.

Important :  Set a space between the last character in the `linux` line and `nouveau.modeset=0`.

Comment: I tried it with ubuntu 16.04 beta 2 , but screen just turned black, can you suggest some other way or should I try this with some other distro ?

Comment: @DikshantRathi : Try it with the parameter nomodeset instead of nouveau.modeset=0 ... in case this also does not work, please check in BIOS whether you can disable the NVIDIA card during the installation and also do not attach an external monitor until the proprietary NVIDIA drivers are installed to the system. :)

Comment: It is Dec 27 2016, I tested with Ubuntu 16.10 on Asus GL 552VX, I have to follow your answer to install Ubuntu, So sad for a popular OS

Comment: @vanduc1102 : Please bare in mind that the developers of the open source nouveau drivers depend on the information they receive from NVIDIA and this process is known to be some kinda hard stuff. So, it's not Ubuntu's fault - most important : the solution to disable the drivers for getting the system installed properly works and is a good alternative to achieve what you wanted. :)

Comment: @cl-netbox Thank for your replying on my comment and tell me the reason why Ubuntu has the issue with NVIDIA, I am the first one vote up this answer , a week ago maybe.

Comment: @vanduc1102 : Thank you very much ! :) In case that you also have trouble while installing the proprietary NVIDIA drivers - this is the most reliable way to make everything work properly, especially with Optimus : http://askubuntu.com/questions/862665/module-nvidia-361-is-not-found/862672#862672 (Installation - Part 2 of the answer)