# Ubuntu 16.04 fan problem on my Asus UX501VW

Tags: 16.04, fan

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 but my PC starts to run fan at maximum speed when I log in. Once installed I tried to find where the problem is, so I have installed `lmsensors`, `fancontrol` and `psensor`. All temps are o.k. (about 30 °C) but fan speed is -1 RPM (on Windows and on Ubuntu 15.10 fans work correctly). Changing video driver (from X.Org to nVidia driver) fans work correctly (and on Psensor fans are about at 2200 RPM) but my battery runs out quickly because of the nVidia Geforce GTX 960M. If I go back to X.Org video driver the problem returns. I have tried  to install `laptop-mode-tools` too, but the problem remains. How can I solve this problem and continue to use X.Org driver?
Thank you so much and sorry for my English.

P.S.: this is the result of `sensor` using nVidia driver

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +38.0°C  (crit = +103.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +39.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +36.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +36.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +34.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +34.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:     2100 RPM
temp1:        +38.0°C
```

## **EDIT:**

I have solved my problem installing Linux kernel 4.6.0 (Ubuntu 16.04 has Linux kernel 4.4.0). [Here's](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/05/install-linux-kernel-4-6-ubuntu-16-04/) a guide to install it and [here](https://marclewis.com/2016/04/25/installing-ubuntu-16-04-lts-on-asus-zenbook-ux501vw/) another solution for my problem (tested) that use Linux kernel 4.3.5.

The second solution slow down system start, so I have used the first one

Comment: Your answer is here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/751784/problem-in-linux-installation-on-asus-rog

Comment: Thank you so much! Now even if I use nVidia Prime with Intel GPU fans are fine. I have added also the line `acpi_osi=` with `nouveau.modeset=0`

Comment: I've find a problem. If I enable nVidia Prime with Intel GPU or if i select X.Org video driver instead of nVidia driver my PC do not want to shutdown or reboot or log out.  As soon as I press one of these buttons the screen turns off but the PC stays on until I press for a while the power button

Comment: Please do not put `SOLVED` in the title, just check the checkmark onto the answer which was most helpful for you. Thank you.

Comment: I have find this solution because the other did not work...Anyway I cancel "Solved" from title

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record, since I have no interest in using the intel gpu, I never have. As an experiment, I used the nvidia gui to change to intel, logged out, and, after login the same fan issue occurred in 15.10,

```
uname -a
Linux deblap2 4.2.0-36-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 15:49:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

thus, as far as I can tell, it is not ubuntu 16.04 specific, and, in the various distros I attempted to install on the laptop, including debian, manjaro, mandriva, it has universally occurred, except that only ubuntu 15.10 installed correctly.

Also more interesting, I could not then revert by using the nvidia gui, as after logout touchpad froze, and I need to hard shutdown.

this is interesting as the problem with the power switch was the main reason i ended up with ubuntu,  as ever other distro I tried had the issue that the power switch and the commands reboot and shutdown did not work as expected.

I thought it was a kernel version issue, or my laptop, same as OP's, or elan or evdev, or coretemp,  but even though arch recommended adding lmsensors and coretemp, coretemp is loaded. thus, the post and answers bring us one step closer, as the issues are somehow gpu related.

best

M

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the exact same fan issue upon installing 16.04 ubuntu version on a ux501vw laptop. I have followed both proposed solutions and actually none have worked (both 4.3.5 and 4.6 kernels). The fan would still run at around 2500 rpm and furthermore the shutdown command would not work. The monitor would blank out and fans would keep spinning but it would not go into full reboot. Finally I have found this post and it worked.

https://askubuntu.com/a/811260/587844.

It is definitely the X.ORG video driver which is buggy. Once I reverted to the NVIDIA one, I could use 16.04 with the 4.6 kernel with no problem. To enable the NVIDIA driver simply open the Software & Updates and navigate to the **Additional Drivers** tab. Then simply select NVIDIA. Hopefully this will help anyone who stumbles upon this page and has faced the same frustrations in finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Had some nvidia/ubuntu 16.04 problems (after update) with my old quadra 1500 gpu. After many attempts i managed to use nvidia driver on a new ubuntu install with some instability.

nvidia monitor indicating high gpu temperature >90º and fan still at 30% pwm, sometimes 40% on some lower temperatures. This is odd!

I've writen this script to monitor temp and control fan as i wait for a fix and to avoid burning the gpu.

https://github.com/neu-rah/nvfan

Dont know if it helps, use at you own risk.
but at least my GPU never reached the red level again.

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue,

What I did, is to install ubuntu 16.10, and the problem with the fan was gone; I still had a login issue, which I was able to solve with this:
[Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Besides that, everything else works perfect with 16.10