# Fanspeed with Ubuntu on ASUS UX501VW

Tags: kernel, asus, fan

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my ASUS UX501VW and the fans are blasting at full speed. I have tried to install the kernel 4.6 (as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765394/ubuntu-16-04-fan-problem-on-my-asus-ux501vw)) and kernel 4.3.5 (as suggested [here](https://marclewis.com/2016/04/25/installing-ubuntu-16-04-lts-on-asus-zenbook-ux501vw/)), but both didn't solve the problem. I have to add that this is my first time installing and using ubuntu, so I am a total noob. Other problems the above guys seemed to have I don't really have, WiFi works perfectly, as does the touchpad. Also I'm running this as a dual boot, Windows 10 is installed on another partition.

Any other suggestions as to what I could do?

Comment: How I solved this back then: Boot with parameter nouveau.modeset=0 to turn off the nouveau graphics driver and then install the nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 0):

For the fan issue, I had to use kernel 4.8-rc1. Install from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

There were stability issues (machine freeze) as well with XOrg. I had to  purge/blacklist the nouveau drivers and use nvidia drivers. I'm using nvidia-367 from the graphics-drivers ppa. It seems stable now, except for an XOrg crash that makes me login twice. I haven't looked into this yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have an ASUS GL552VM with a gtx960 and had the same problem : The fan just started to go crazy as soon as I logged in ..

Installing the 4.6 kernel and enabling the NVIDIA driver one did the trick!

cheers

Comment: Hi @qbadx, well come to ask.ubuntu, It would be really helpful if you supplied more information as to how exactly you installed your "NVIDIA drivers".