# Can not install Ubuntu 16.04 or 16.10 on Asus GL 552vx

Tags: 16.04, asus, 16.10

I have **Asus GL552VX** with Corei7 6700hq, 16Gb RAM and 128 Gb SSD.

I tried with both **Ubuntu 16.10** and **16.04**.

I create bootable USB with **Rufus**.

And the installation stop at the loading screen forever.... ( so sad )

Does anyone know what is the issue?

And which version of ubuntu can be installed on my machine ?

Thank

Comment: I solved the issue with the anwser on http://askubuntu.com/questions/751784/problem-with-installation-on-asus-rog  thank.

Answer (score 0):

Rufus and other live usb creators fail to create a bootable USB in many cases. Use dd command instead. 
'sudo dd if=/iso of=/dev/sdx bs=4M && sync'
Where /iso is the path where the iso is in your hdd and x is the letter for the usb, as shown in 'lsblk'