# Module 'nvidia-361' is not found

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I tried to install my graphics card on my ASUS G552VW-DM475T which is an intel Core i7-6700HQ (+intel graphic 520) and a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M without success (for about 5 days). The last thing that I tried was this -> from a [Russian document](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/bumblebee-xenial). Here are the commands of the document:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:neon1ks/bumblebee
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends nvidia-361 nvidia-settings bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus
sudo gpasswd -a $USER bumblebee
sudo systemctl enable bumblebeed

sudo gedit /etc/modules
i915
bbswitch

sudo gedit /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
Driver=nvidia
KernelDriver=nvidia-361
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-361:/usr/lib32/nvidia-361
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-361/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules

reboot
```

But when I restart the computer the screen is black, like if it is turned off. When I execute `grep /var/sys/syslog` for `bumblebeed` I get an error saying `Module 'nvidia-361' is not found`, which I don't understand.
And I ran `cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch = ON`. So the screen is using my graphics card but not the `xserver`, which is using the intel graphics. It seems that I have to use bumblebee because of the NVIDIA Optimus technology. Please assist, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you have a quite new CPU and GPU - there might be some incompatibilities. Use the following method to install the NVIDIA drivers. First of all uninstall the currently installed NVIDIA drivers and bumblebee ... the actual solution to switch between the two graphics adapters is `nvidia-prime`.

Boot the computer, mark the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the linux line. Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot Ubuntu.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo apt purge nvidia* bumblebee
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge neon1ks/bumblebee
sudo reboot
```

Now install the latest official NVIDIA drivers 375 (supporting NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M).

Boot the computer, mark the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the linux line. Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot Ubuntu.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-375 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Important : Set a space between the last letter in the `linux` line and `nouveau.modeset=0`.
Switch between intel and NVIDIA graphics from NVIDIA X Server Settings | PRIME Profiles.

Comment: i can't believe it seems that it's work ! I spent i don't know how much time to test differents things, thanks to you !

Comment: @cl-netbox you are a genius. It worked perfectly using your instructions. Thank you so much, I was giving up using my graphic card...